# How is this 'soft landing' effect called?

Tags: javascript

Please have a look at [www.myprovence.fr](http://www.myprovence.fr). Click the links at the fixed top and see that the page does not just jump to its anchors, but slides the last few centimeters, or lands softly as I would call it. I want to figure out how this is done, but I don't know what to look for in the (compressed/minified and extensive) source code, or what to google for. And Firebug does not make it clear either. How is this called, what should I look for?

Comment: This is what they use `http://www.myprovence.fr/js/uzik.js`.

Comment: @Dream Eater - That script makes a whole lot more sense. But how did you distill that URL from the one Firebug is showing: http://prntscr.com/wxizw. What's the mechanism behind the original URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it took another, essential building block, which had to be repaired first, but with that and the building blocks Asad handed, I got it to work -- and beautifully, I might add. Down to IE7 (6 not tested)! See http://bit.ly/XWbvZw. All the info is in the code and the comments.

Thanks for jumping in!

Answer (score 2):

A quadratic ease out function should accomplish the effect you are looking for. This and other easing functions are provided with [this plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) (or you could write your own). You can examine the easing functions included with the library [here](http://easings.net/).

Answer (score 0):

They use jQuery in combination with an easing function. Chris Coyier put out something similar which you can see the code and demo here: [link](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/)

You just need to have the nav links go something like this:

```
<a href="#one">Scroll to Section One</a>
<a href="#two">Scroll to Section Two</a>
```

And the sections you want to scroll to would be like:

```
<div id="one">Section One</div>
<div id="two">Section Two</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't slow down as the viewport approaches the link, so it is irrelevant.